# Multi-column CSS layout with rounded borders

Tags: css, layout, html, border

**Problem:**

I am trying to create a multi-column CSS layout with borders that look something in line with this picture:

[image]

**Code:**

```
<div style="border-radius:4px; border: 1px solid #ddd;">

        <div style="display:block;float:left;width:50%;">
            <div><b>F&ouml;rfattare:</b> '.$authors.'<br></div>
            <b>Handledare:</b> '.$row['Supervisor'].'<br>
            <b>Examinator:</b> '.$row['Examiner'].'<br>
            <b>Design av studie:</b> '.$design.'
        </div>

        <div style="display:block;float:left;width:50%;">
            <b>Examinationsdatum:</b> '.$row['ExaminationDate'].'<br>
            <b>Niv&aring;:</b> '.$level.' ('.$credits.')<br>
            <b>Kommentar:</b> '.$row['Comments'].'<br>
            <b>&Ouml;vrigt:</b> '.$row['Participants'].' deltagare, '.$row['Reference'].' referenser
        </div>

</div>
```

**The above-mentioned code will produce the following:**

[image]

**Question:**

What needs to be modified so I can get the horizontal and vertical lines to the box?

Comment: Why not use a table??

Comment: Why don't use table for this? You can give the table a border-radius, too.

Comment: Because I'm using an html to pdf converter that doesn't allow the border-radius for the table element and therefore I'm forced to use CSS.

Comment: Which converter are you using? You should have mentioned this when you first asked the question.

Comment: I agree with theBigChalk here.  People tend to think that using tables is wrong, because at some point of history, many web developers used tables to code the layout of the pages.  In this particular case, using a table is not only easy, but also correct.

Comment: more than a table it looks like a definition list to me - laid on two columns

Comment: I disagree with thirtydot, OPs question is much more general and helpful to the public in it's current form.

Comment: @thirtydot You are absolutely right and I forgot to mention this, for this I am sorry. The converter I am using is called mPDF and it works fine but can't handle border-radius for the table-element.

Comment: Using a table would be easy and more robust than some CSS solutions with certain constraints so a decorative table is acceptable (I can live with that) but it wouldn't be correct: headers on columns 1 and 3, data on columns 2 and 4 would give poor semantic, a too complex data table.

Comment: @kexxcream What are your compatibility constraints? [CSS3 Multiple column layout](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) has good support except on IE, IE9 included alas, but there's a polyfill for that ... if you don't care about IE9- without JS and aren't too preoccupied by performances on IE9- ;)

Comment: @enthdegree: This question is useless to future visitors anyway. Think about it: without the constraints of this PDF converter, the correct answer is to use a `<table>` to show this table of data. None of the answers are using `<table>`.

Comment: oh yeah i agree with that for sure, I was looking at the answers in the context of that this question, in it's current form, can also apply to multi-column rounded border layouts that contain non-tabular data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the CSS to look like this:

```
.row {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.top {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.bottom {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.outerBox {
    margin: 10px;
}​
```

Then have your markup look like this:

```
<div class="outerBox">
    <div class="row top">
        <span class="left"><b>F&ouml;rfattare:</b> '.$authors.'</span><span class="right"><b>Examinationsdatum:</b> '.$row['ExaminationDate'].'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="left"><b>Handledare:</b> '.$row['Supervisor'].'</span><span class="right"><b>Niv&aring;:</b> '.$level.' ('.$credits.')</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="left"><b>Examinator:</b> '.$row['Examiner'].'</span><span class="right"><b>Kommentar:</b> '.$row['Comments'].'</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row bottom">
        <span class="left"><b>Design av studie:</b> '.$design.'</span><span class="right"><b>&Ouml;vrigt:</b> '.$row['Participants'].' deltagare, '.$row['Reference'].' referenser</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CAVEAT:** The formatting will break if you put a space between the `span`s on an individual line, so don't break them; otherwise, take this solution and work out something that doesn't break =)    ​

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/XhnBE/

**EDIT:** It seems that mPDF doesn't like `inline-block`, so change this part of your CSS:

```
.left {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/XhnBE/1/

Comment: Thank you for the solution and it looks pretty much right. But unfortunately it breaks for some reason (and I haven't modified the code) when parsing it through mPDF - http://screencast.com/t/WSBLP5ybZO

Comment: Now I got somewhere. I switched all span elements to div elements and got this: http://screencast.com/t/ME9Vl5OCp - only thing left is to make sure the second rows move to the first and float right.

Comment: That was easy, I added float:left to .left and to .right. This resulted in: http://screencast.com/t/H15e23Kaa

Comment: This works only if span is changed for div, but otherwise the solution works perfectly!

Comment: One final question: how would I add padding to these different "columns" without breaking the design? Say 5px.

Comment: The quickest way (a little dirty, but effective) is to add this rule: `.row b {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 5px; 
}` -- just adjust the line-height for proper padding on top and bottom.
​

Answer (score 3):

You could use two lists side by side:

```
<div style="border-radius:4px; border: 1px solid #ddd;">

    <ul style="display:block;float:left;width:50%;">
        <li><b>F&ouml;rfattare:</b> '.$authors.'</li>
        <li><b>Handledare:</b> '.$row['Supervisor'].'</li>
        <li><b>Examinator:</b> '.$row['Examiner'].'</li>
        <li><b>Design av studie:</b> '.$design.'</li>
    </ul>

    <ul style="display:block;float:left;width:50%;">
        <li><b>Examinationsdatum:</b> '.$row['ExaminationDate'].'</li>
        <li><b>Niv&aring;:</b> '.$level.' ('.$credits.')</li>
        <li><b>Kommentar:</b> '.$row['Comments'].'</li>
        <li><b>&Ouml;vrigt:</b> '.$row['Participants'].' deltagare, '.$row['Reference'].' referenser</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

You'll need to add some styles to get rid of the default styles for lists and add you borders to the top, bottom and sides of your `li`s .

A down side of this is that you'll have to give your `li`s fixed heights so the borders line up.

Comment: I think a definition list makes more sense here as there are labels and values but nevertheless I +1 your answer as the data in the question does not look like tabular to me

Comment: it also make more sense, semantically, to have a single list and float the elements (and play with width: 50% or similar and other css to display them properly)

Comment: @Luca I agree about the single list, I was just giving a solution which was close to the original code to illustrate how the code could easily be changed. I'd use `display: inline-block` rather than `float` on the `li`s in that case though.

Comment: I guess that with inline-block he would get that nasty gap between two elements, similar to display: inline?

Comment: Aren't the two ul supposed to be next to each other in the above code? I'm getting them under each other. Should borders be only added to the li elements?

Comment: @Luca Yes, you need to remove all white- space between the `li`s if you use `display:inline-block`, which is annoying. On the other hand, if you use `float`s you have to use some tricks to get the `ul` to recognize that they're there in some cases (adding a border around them, for example).

Comment: yeah with float there's always the need to clear the elements - clearfix hack or I personally like hoverflow: hidden (on the list) when possible

Comment: @kexxcream [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BNsKy/) shows how they should appear. (I haven't done anything about rounded borders and other styles here)

Comment: @Gareth For some reason I'm not getting the lists next to each other, I wonder if this is a limitation of mPDF which is the HTML2PDF converter I am using. In addition, when applying the li css I get no different results. The jsFiddle you showed looks right but doesn't work for some reason with mPDF.

Comment: @kexxcream It sounds like that might be the issue but I've never used mPDF I'm afraid, so I can't help you with that. :-(

Comment: @Gareth No problem, saluce gave me a helping hand here. Thank you all for your time and effort. It's very kind, and I highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your marke-up. You need a table or more boxes to do this. I think tables would be easier to manage... and somehow this is a case tables are for.
Or you take a bg-image... but I *won't* recommend this

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using an html to pdf converter that doesn't allow the border-radius for the table element.

Comment: then "simulate" a table with divs or something. Don't know... floats or absolute positioning. That's your decision
or divs in tables to make the borders ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/eNEzs/

It's enough to correct your css a little bit and wrapp items in div's.

```
<div style="border-radius:4px; border: 1px solid #ddd; margin: 20px;">

        <div class="block">
            <div><b>F&ouml;rfattare:</b> '.$authors.'</div>
            <div><b>Handledare:</b> '.$row['Supervisor'].'</div>
            <div><b>Examinator:</b> '.$row['Examiner'].'</div>
            <div><b>Design av studie:</b> '.$design.'</div>
        </div>

        <div class="block">
            <div><b>Examinationsdatum:</b> '.$row['ExaminationDate'].'</div>
            <div><b>Niv&aring;:</b> '.$level.' ('.$credits.')</div>
            <div><b>Kommentar:</b> '.$row['Comments'].'</div>
            <div><b>&Ouml;vrigt:</b> '.$row['Participants'].</div>
        </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>        
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.block {
     display:block;
     float:left;
     width:50%; 
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
.block:first-child {
     border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
 }
.block div {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 }
.block div:last-child {
     border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

But I would **recommend you to simply change elements to a table or list (ul or ol)**. Above solution is simply for this particular exmaple.

Comment: This design will break if the width is too narrow.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each cell in a `div` instead of using `br`, and add `border-left` and `border-bottom` on the appropriate element. If you still want to use `50%` width, then use `box-sizing: border-box;` to keep it from wrapping.

[See this jsfiddle for one way to do it](http://jsfiddle.net/sveinatle/GY8Fr/2/), though you should use classes to properly select which elements to apply the different styles to.